Proving that ZF is Artemov-consistent
As discussed in another MO question, Sergei Artemov has proposed that the standard formalization Con(PA) of "PA is consistent" is flawed, and has proposed a different way to formalize "proving that PA is consistent" (which he claims is closer to Hilbert's original intention).
Setting aside the debates over the "correctness" of Artemov's formalization, we can ask a technical question:

Can PA prove that ZF is consistent (in Artemov's sense)?

Artemov shows that, according to his definitions, PA proves that PA is consistent, and suggests that Hilbert's program is not yet dead. But what Hilbert wanted wasn't an arithmetic proof that arithmetic is consistent; he wanted a finitary proof that set theory is consistent. If we provisionally accept Artemov's definitions, can Hilbert's desire for a finitary proof of the consistency of set theory be realized?

REMARK: Arguably, the present question is a duplicate of Does PA prove (Artemov-style) the consistency of a stronger system? and the present question was indeed, at one point in time, closed as a duplicate. However, the community subsequently decided to reopen the present question, perhaps in part because Artemov himself has posted an answer that clarifies some things.

If ZF is actually consistent, then PA proves of each standard $n$ that it is not the proof of a contradiction in ZF. And since ZF proves of each of its finite fragments that that fragment is consistent, what we have is that ZF proves, of every particular $n$, that PA proves that it is not the proof of a contradiction in ZF. Can you say what more would be required for Artemov consistency?

I recommend looking at the comment thread below my answer to the linked question; at least one of the relevant "proof" notions does not in fact (according to Artemov) have a formal definition.

So it seems that if we have ZF as the meta theory, then we can prove that PA proves ZF is Artemov consistent, based on the observation of my comment.

@Joel David Hamkins. This is correct: ZF selector proves its consistency; see my JLC paper.

I had thought I was claiming more, namely, that ZF proves that PA proves the consistency (in your sense) of ZF. Specifically, ZF proves of every metatheoretic numeral $n$ that PA proves that it is not the proof of a contradiction in ZF. Perhaps I've misunderstood, but I had thought you were claiming that PA doesn't prove these things? I am unsure whether I am allowed to assume ZF in the metatheory when discussing these issues about what PA proves or not. If I do have ZF in the metatheory, then isn't it correct that PA prove the consistency of ZF in your sense? Or is this a misunderstanding?

Essentially a duplicate of Does PA prove (Artemov-style) the consistency of a stronger system? I think?

@ChristopherKing I forgot about that question. But in that question, there was a misreading of Artemov's definition. Still, I would be okay with closing the current question as a duplicate. I wouldn't want to delete the current question, though, since it elicited a response from Artemov himself.

@Joel David Hamkins. When formalized, a selector consistency proof has three occurrences of proof predicates ":," $v:s(x):\neg x:\bot$ where $s(x)$ is a selector, v is a verifier, and $\neg x:\bot$ comes from the object theory. For ZF consistency in ZF, both $\neg x:\bot$ and $s(x):$ should be ZF proof predicates, whereas $v:$ is just a coding bookkeeping, usually performed by PA or its appropriate fragment. In this sense, we both agree that ZF proves its consistency. When we try to formalize the claim that PA proves ZF, then $s(x):$ should be the PA proof predicate, which does not work.

@SergeiArtemov But it does work, if I understand things correctly, if in that case we take $v:$ as the ZF proof predicate, right? This is what I had meant by having ZF in the meta theory. That is, ZF proves of every numeral $n$ that PA proves of it that it is not the proof of a contradiction in ZF. Those are the three instances of proof predicates, in this natural language way of saying it, right?

@Joel David Hamkins. Well, perhaps elevating the coding theory to the almighty ZF could indeed work for different reasons. However, this still smells like begging the question since the ZF selector proves ZF. Anyway, thank you for the cute observation that the power of the coding theory can compensate for other weaknesses.

@PaceNielsen. Noah Schweber's first analysis of my version of "entailment" has been based of misunderstanding. So, I am not responsible for what you call $P! A ^\ast$, let alone for proving Con$(P! A ^\ast)$ in $P! A ^\ast$. Proving consistency is a delicate matter, and suggesting themselves simplifications do not necessarily work. I would advise reading the corresponding JLC_2024 paper.

@SergeiArtemov If we allow selector proofs as an additional tool in our toolkit, then doesn't Con^S(PA) fail to capture consistency because it fails to capture that selector proofs provide a possible additional avenue to a contradiction?

@SergeiArtemov What precisely is Noah Schweber's misunderstanding in his answer here? Noah's answer actually corrects a misunderstanding of your paper that originated in a different answer to the question. I have read your paper, Noah's answer, and the many comments below it, and I still don't see anything wrong with Noah's answer.

@PaceNielsen. A perfect question. Thank you. In fact, selector proofs do not extend the proving power of PA w.r.t. formulas, it remains the same good old PA. Specifically, Proposition 5.3.ii in the JLC_2024 paper (Proposition 2(ii) in the arXiv preprint) states that whenever a serial property is (selector) provable in PA, each of its instances is provable as a formula. The proof is constructive and formalizable in PA. So, no special new consistency proof is needed: since PA does not prove 0=1, none of the provable serial properties contains 0=1 as its member.

@AlexKruckman. I see this unfortunate misconception still alive despite my short clarifying replies on MO and precise formulations and examples in the paper. I need to craft a real-size comment to Noah Schweber's attempted exposition of my construction. More time is needed for this. I hope to do this today.

@AlexKruckman I think the problem is as follows. (Sergei, feel free to correct me if I get something wrong.)  There is a metamathematical statement Z that is equivalent to the metamathematical statement "PA is consistent", but the proof of that equivalence uses the idea of selector proofs.  This equivalence is not provable in PA, only in a strictly stronger metatheory.  We can encode "PA is consistent" as the arithmetic sentence Con(PA), which PA does not prove.  We can encode Z as Con^S(PA), which PA does prove. (continued...)

We have not affected what PA proves or does not prove.  We have not changed formal entailment.  But we have assumed stronger (non-PA) metatheoretic tools (by allowing selector proofs).  Thus, in Artemov's abstract, when he writes "PA proves its own consistency", I believe this means "PA proves a statement that is equivalent (under a stronger theory than PA, but weak in some relevant ways) to consistency".

@PaceNielsen. I will reply with corrections, but I'm too busy with other replies.

@PaceNielsen. PA proves a formula $F$ has been rigorous, and PA proves a serial property ${F}$ is equally rigorous. "PA proves the consistency of PA" has not been rigorous in the old von Neumann sense because it relies on a specific formalization of PA consistency (as Con(PA), as Rosser Con(PA), etc). "PA selector proves the consistency of PA" is equally not rigorous for similar reasons. Proving consistency is easier since it suffices to come up with one convincing case, whereas proving unprovability is impossible because of this lack of rigor in the definitions. Such is life.

@PaceNielsen. Your analysis is pretty good, but some principal comments/suggestions can be made, with your kind permission. "There is a metamathematical statement Z that is equivalent to the metamathematical statement "PA is consistent", but the proof of that equivalence uses the idea of selector proofs." No it does not, just a logic reasoning in some metatheory with quantifiers over numerals (hence extending PA).  It boils down to accepting that "for all numerals n, F(n)" is logically equivalent to the set of sentences {F(0), F(1), F(2), ...}. This is more basic than selector proofs.

"We can encode "PA is consistent" as the arithmetic sentence Con(PA)." This also requires reasoning in a metatheory with numeral quantifiers but with a dubious and false assumption that PA-quantifiers are equivalent to numeral quantifiers. You have to assume that "for all numerals n, F(n)" is not logically equivalent to the set of sentences {F(0), F(1), F(2), ...}. This is why I strongly prefer Con^S(PA) to Con(PA). The tension between "PA is consistent" and Con(PA) is that the former uses numeric quantifiers (or their equivalents) whereas Con(PA) uses non-equivalent PA-quantifiers.

"But we have assumed stronger (non-PA) metatheoretical tools (by allowing selector proofs)." Selector proofs are not metatheoretical tools; they are native PA tools that prove serial properties that are totally consistent with all other PA tools. This is like you have never used reverse in your car, but this feature has always been available. Somebody brings this to your attention, and you begin using the reverse in the same old car.

@SergeiArtemov Thanks for the clarifications! Accepting that selector proofs are a native PA tool, then they only "prove serial properties" when you either (i) expand your sense of formal derivation (as Noah did) or (ii) expand your meta-notion of "prove" to accept serial proofs as a valid means of meta-verification. Sure, this can be like a feature in your car that you never used before. But so is using PA+Con(PA) in your metatheory, which runs counter to not assuming PA is consistent to begin with. (BTW, writing {F(0),F(1),...} starts introducing second order logic into metatheory.)

@PaceNielsen. "PA+Con(PA) in your metatheory" - I do not use PA+Con(PA) in my metatheory. Using sets of formulas in metatheory is common practice: cf. the textbook deduction theorem: "for a given set of formulas $\Gamma$, ...  ." My metatheory is standard for PA. We only need numeral quantifiers "for any numeral n..." to transit from "PA is consistent," which, modulo to Goedel numbering, uses numeral quantifiers to its faithful PA form. Picking Con(PA) as "PA is consistent" was a hack job: we naively replaced numeral quantifiers with PA quantifiers. So, we must work with Con^S(PA).

@PaceNielsen. "ii) expand your meta-notion of "prove" to accept serial proofs as a valid means of meta-verification" - this is the option I am suggesting in the JLC_2024 paper. Selector proofs are embedded into mathematical practice: induction principle, product of polynomials, tautologies. Here is a quote: "If we don’t accept selector proofs, we have to admit that such basic mathematical facts as induction, propositional tautologies, product of polynomials, etc., are not provable in arithmetic. Moreover, that consistency is unprovable for the same reason: selector proofs are not included."

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Thank you for your interest and for advertising my work.
The answer to this specific question (as well as to most of the questions asked on my work in this venue) is given in the paper published in JLC: Sergei Artemov. Serial properties, selector proofs and the provability of consistency. Journal of Logic and Computation,
https://doi.org/10.1093/logcom/exae034, Published: 26 July 2024.
(Ask me if you have trouble downloading the paper from JLC.)
Here is the answer (a quote from the paper):

Whereas our methods allow proving the consistency of a theory in itself, we don’t know how to prove in T the consistency of a theory S, which is strictly stronger than T. In particular, Kurahashi-Sinclaire’s observation that prohibits PA from proving the consistency scheme for PA+ConPA shows also that PA cannot prove the consistency of ZF.
This paper refutes the Unprovability of Consistency thesis, and these findings have their foundational value. Though this does not reach the goals of Hilbert’s consistency program, it removes a principal roadblock on its way.

So, my humble contribution to Hilbert’s program is mostly moral

It removes the widely accepted misconception that G2 killed Hilbert’s program.

Moreover, it shows that this misconception was unwarranted from the very beginning, the 1930s. The unprovability of consistency argument was based on the assumption that any PA-consistency proof in PA should be PA provably equivalent to Con(PA), which had no justification then (cf. the JLC paper for the details) and now is proven false.


BTW, we don't need Hilbert's authority to show that Con(PA) is not equivalent to "PA is consistent" over PA. Here is a clean math argument with some obvious technical assumptions like "PA derivations are finite syntactic objects", "Goedel numbers of PA-derivations are numerals," "Godel numbering preserves the elementary computational structure of PA-derivations, e.g., D is not a proof of 0=1 iff the code of D is not a code of a sequence containing the line 0=1," etc.
Here is the argument

Consistency of PA is a property "no formal derivation in PA proves 0=1." This is a canonical textbook definition.

Godel numbering transliterates this property in its equivalent form (*): "for any numeral n, n is not a code of a PA-derivation containing the line 0=1."

Since quantification over numerals is not expressible in PA, we have to use some other means to equivalently represent "for any numeral n ... ". An obvious way to do this is by a p.r. string of sentences (which we call the consistency scheme Con^S(PA):
"0 is not a code of a PA-derivation containing the line 0=1,"
"1 is not a code of a PA-derivation containing the line 0=1,"
"2 is not a code of a PA-derivation containing the line 0=1,"
etc.
It is immediate that (*) is mathematically equivalent to Con^S(PA) without any meta-assumptions about PA.

Con(PA) is strictly stronger than Con^S(PA) in PA (an easy exercise), hence Con(PA) is strictly stronger than (*).



I'm still confused about which statements are formal/precise and which ones are informal. When you say "In particular, Kurahashi-Sinclaire’s observation that prohibits PA from proving the consistency scheme for PA+ConPA shows also that PA cannot prove the consistency of ZF" which category is the bolded part?

-1 for the "BTW...", which adds nothing relevant to Timothy Chow's question (which grants your nonstandard views on consistency assertions). Your argument begs the question, as I pointed out in an earlier comment. It is only a proof that that Con(PA) is not equivalent to "PA is consistent" over PA if you have already decided to interpret "PA is consistent" in PA as the infinitely many statements "$n$ does not code a PA derivation of $\bot$" for each numeral $n$.

I think you have (in your paper on the topic) made an interesting philosophical argument about the proper way to formalize "PA is consistent" in PA. I don't buy it, but I think it's interesting and valuable. What I'm taking issue with is trying to frame this as a mathematical argument

@AlexKruckman. I strongly disagree. The whole story has a deep mathematical substance: quantifiers over numerals are intrinsically different from PA quantifiers. Do you want to do anything with it, or just ignore this and reduce to buying PA-quantifiers as quantifiers over numerals? If you decide to do something else instead, then what exactly? The scheme Con^S(PA) is equivalent to (*), whereas Con(PA) is not. What do you choose?

@NoahSchweber. Your comment may sound misleading. All known notions of consistency proof contain informal components, e.g., the unprovability of consistency argument uses the informal notion of consistency formalization. My take on the consistency proof follows (as I hope) Hilbert's format that a T-consistency proof in a theory S is
(A). A rigorous mathematical proof of T-consistency,
and
(B). A formalization of (A) in S.
(A) is not necessarily formal, and its formalization depends on many previous choices that we cannot foresee.

@SergeiArtemov I genuinely don't understand how my question can be misleading. The problem with this sort of approach to presenting mathematical claims, and more generally (to quote from a previous comment of yours) the "you know it when you see it" style, is that maybe I don't know-upon-seeing the same things that you do. I think that's the case here.

Whether or not one accepts the statement "$Con(PA)$ is an adequate formalization of 'PA is consistent,'" one can accept the purely formal statement "$[PA\not\vdash\perp]\implies [PA\not\vdash Con(PA)]$." That's what I'm looking for in your claims: a purely formal statement which, independently of whether I accept your philosophical stance, I can recognize as true. That is what I don't see so far as soon as "selector proofs" enter the picture, and I think this is a serious problem. I truly do not understand your claim that these exhibit the same degree/role of informality. But I'll bow out.

@NoahSchweber. Everybody is entitled to have his/her own (mis)understanding. The only thing I expect is to apply them fairly, not selectively. I can live with your understanding Goedel's Second theorem, but not understanding the Unprovability of Consistency thesis (PA cannot prove its consistency) as not formal enough for you.

@SergeiArtemov I do extend exactly the same demand for precision: in any context where I am not certain that I and my interlocutors all understand "PA is consistent" as being shorthand for the same string of symbols, I check that (i) they do in fact have a formal counterpart in mind and (ii) it's the same as mine before continuing on the topic. Admittedly, this doesn't come up very often. But this is what I view as the appropriate role of informal language in mathematical claims and arguments (as opposed to discussion of their import/motivation of course):

that such informality is only appropriate when it is clear what formal strings are "had in mind" so to speak. This is a principle I apply completely uniformly, and is what motivated my questions to you in the first place.

@AlexKruckman. Since you are the first person who expressed disagreement with a specific step of my (well-advertised ) argument 1-4 that Con(PA) is stronger than PA consistency, I am truly interested. I see, you disagree with (3), which converts “for all numerals n, F(n)” for a specific p.r. formula F(x) to “F(0), F(1), F(2), … .” I see them as equivalent without invoking any meta-assumptions about PA. Direction => is obvious. Direction <=: suppose for some numeral m, F(m) does not hold. Then the m-th element in the string “F(0), F(1), F(2), … ” is false. What exactly bothers you here?

@SergeiArtemov I thought my comment above and the linked comment made my objection clear, but I'll try again. You claim to make a mathematical argument regarding the equivalence (or not) of Con(PA) and "PA is consistent". That's nonsense, of course, because these two concepts live at different levels: Con(PA) is  formal, while "PA is consistent" Is informal. So we must first decide how to formalize "PA is consistent". But once we decide how to formalize "PA is consistent", the mathematical question of equivalence (or not) trivializes. (Continued in next comment)

So we're left with the question of the proper formalization of "PA is consistent" which is a philosophical question, not a mathematical one. That's my objection. As for where I stand on the philosophical question:  I'm hardly the first person to express disagreement here! As I said, I think your argument has merits and is worthy of discussion (that's why I'm here), but I think that Timothy Chow and Noah Schweber have written coherent and convincing objections.

I don't understand the phrase "quantification over numerals is not expressible in PA". I mean, it is technically true that the symbols $\forall x$ are just that, symbols.  But once they are interpreted in a model, where the domain of that model is the set of numerals, than those symbols are truly interpreted as quantification over numerals. Moreover, even if we grant (3), then all quantifications in PA are suspect, including the (many!) quantifications in "0 is not a code of a PA-derivation containing the line 0=1" as well as in the induction axiom of PA.

@AlexKruckman. You are the first person who tried to be specific about your objections to my argument that Con(PA) is stronger than PA-consistency. I hoped for a meaningful discussion about mathematics, details of formalization, stability under Goedel numerations, etc. I feel disappointed: your “formalization is a philosophical question” is a step to bail out of a discussion, sorry. If you are ready to talk seriously, please answer my specific question: whether “for all numerals n, F(n)” and “F(0), F(1), F(2), … ” are equivalent or not.

@PaceNielsen. PA quantifiers coincide with numeral quantifiers in the standard model. This does not make all quantifications in PA suspects. For most of the questions, PA quantifiers provide a good approximation to numeral quantifiers: we prove Fermat’s Little Theorem in PA and claim that it is true in the standard model. However, if a sentence is independent in PA, like Con(PA), we have to resort to special tricks to emulate numeral quantifiers faithfully. BTW, "0 is not a code of a PA-derivation containing the line 0=1” is quantifier-free in PA (with p.r. terms) and hence is immune.

What is the key mathematical innovation in your work?

I did not intend to engage in a discussion here of the question of what is the appropriate formalization of "PA is consistent" in PA - the comment section below your answer to an entirely different question is neither a convenient nor appropriate place to have such a discussion. I merely objected to the framing of your argument as a mathematical proof of the non-equivalence.

@MonroeEskew. Thank you for this question. I believe this paper outlines a proof theory of serial properties (and applies it to prove PA consistency in PA, with foundational implications).

@AlexKruckman. Foundational work often requires a responsible formalization part, which makes rigorous but informal notions completely formal, followed by the usual symbol grinding. Think of Goedel's (First) incompleteness theorem, which is widely accepted as the top mathematical result. Let me know when you will be open to this sort of discussion; no pressure.

@AlexKruckman. As for objections (there were some, not many), they were of the sort “I don’t like it at all,” “We don’t do it this way,” “I don’t understand the informal part,” etc ., expressed before reading the final text of the article. Such comments sound like a priori rejections rather than objections. So, no reasonable objections expressed so far “at all.” I hoped that you had something specific to discuss … .

@SergeiArtemov When you say "for all numerals n, F(n)", I take it that "for all numerals" is a metatheoretic phrase, but is F(n) a formal string, or a metatheoretic assertion? If it's a formal string, then "for all numerals n, F(n)" does not make any sense. If it's a metatheoretic assertion, then F(0), F(1), F(2), ... doesn't make sense because for any normal metatheory, infinitely long sentences are not allowed.

@all - please note that the software has flagged this post for a large number of comments. It might be worth taking this discussion elsewhere to resolve, if it's not going to wrap up soon, and then report back if and when there is a resolution.

@SergeiArtemov is there anything wrong with this answer?

@TimothyChow. A short answer is "F(n) is both a formal string and a metatheoretic assertion." To keep things simple, consider the following case: F(x) is a primitive recursive formula in the language of PA with p.r. terms.  Then F(n) is an instance of a p.r. the formula, which makes sense as a meta-theoretic assertion, as well as for PA. Whereas F(n) is a legal sentence, the object {F(0), F(1), F(2), ... } not necessarily should be viewed as a "sentence." It is a series of sentences, normal in metamathematics, cf. the deduction theorem $\Gamma, A \vdash B$ iff $\Gamma \vdash A\rightarrow B$.

@ChristopherKing. This "answer" is irrelevant to my proof; Emil Jerabek himself admitted it in the comments. Loosely, Jerabek's argument is a constructive version of the consistency proof "via the standard model" considered as an example to avoid in my JLC_2024 paper (and in the 2024 arXiv preprint). Jerabek's argument uses the assumption that PA is consistent (hence $\neg n:\bot$ is true) and refers to the classical result that any true p.r. sentence is provable in PA. I am proving the consistency of PA without assuming its consistency.

FYI: here is another post arguing that G2 doesn't stop Hilbert's program (with a fairly different argument): Completing half of Hilbert's program: Foundations that are conservative over Peano Arithmetic
